# Handling nested JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm attempting to retrieve data from within a nested JSON data using Python.

Abbreviated example of the JSON data:

```
{

    "daily" : {
        "1524182400000" : 438,
        "1524268800000" : 438,
        "1524355200000" : 437,
        "1524441600000" : 437,
        "1524528000000" : 432
    }
}
```

As you see, each of the above keys is a unix timestamp and the overall object is constantly updated with new key/value pairs.

While I am easily able to retrieve the data if I know the timestamp I don't know how I get the value of the latest timestamp.

I would usually complete this in PHP with the below code and selecting the array position:

```
foreach ($data["daily"] as $timedate => $value) {
    array_push($ValueArray, $value);
    array_push($ValueDate, $timedate);
}
```

How do I get this in Python?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so you want to grab the last key in the nested dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry you're looking for is `prices['daily'][max(prices['daily'], key=int)]`.

`max(prices['daily'], key=int)` iterates over the keys and find the largest (aka, most recent) one. Setting `key=int` ensures the function does a numerical, rather than lexical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

just use the equivalent of `foreach` in python:

```
for timedate, value in tmp['daily'].items():
    # Do something with timedate or value...
```

It works exactly like the foreach on php.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are loking for, this will work:

```
json_data['daily'][sorted(json_data['daily'].keys())[-1]]
```